# mysql union query

Tags: php, mysql

The table that contains information about members has a structure like:

```
   id   |    fname    |    pic    |   status
--------------------------------------------------
   1    |     john    |   a.jpg   |     1
   2    |     mike    |   b.jpg   |     1
   3    |     any     |   c.jpg   |     1
   4    |     jacky   |   d.jpg   |     1
```

Table for list of friends looks like:

```
  myid  |   date     |    user   
-------------------------------
    1   | 01-01-2011 |     4
    2   | 04-01-2011 |     3
```

I want to make a query that will as result print users from "friendlist" table that contains photos and names of that users from "members" table  of both, myid (those who adding) and user (those who are added).

That table in this example will look like:

```
   myid   |   myidname  |    myidpic   |  user  |  username  |  userpic  |  status   
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1    |     john    |    a.jpg     |   4    |    jacky   |   d.jpg   |     1
     2    |     mike    |    b.jpg     |   3    |    any     |   c.jpg   |     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
    m1.id AS myid,
    m1.fname AS myidname,
    m1.pic AS myidpic,
    m2.id AS user,
    m2.fname AS username,
    m2.pic AS userpic,
    m1.status
FROM
    members m1
        INNER JOIN friends f ON m1.id = f.myid
        INNER JOIN members m2 ON f.user = m2.id
```